# Como realizar una prueba unitaria en laravel sin registrar los datos de prueba en la base de datos?

Tags: laravel, pruebas-unitarias, phpunit

Tengo la siguiente prueba:

```
public function testExample()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $response = $this->actingAs($user,'api')->json('POST', 'api/rangos?api_token='.$user->api_token,
        [
            "denominacion"=>"Visitante",
            "nivel"=>"1"
        ]
    );
    $response->assertStatus(201);
    $response->assertJsonStructure([
        "id",
        "denominacion",
        "nivel",
        "miembros",
        "updated_at",
        "created_at"
    ]);
}
```

La funcion a la que hago la prueba unitaria es la siguiente:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $data=new Rango($request->all());
    $data->save();
    return response()->json($data->load("miembros"),201);
}
```

La prueba unitaria pasa de forma exitosa, el problema es que al ejecutar la prueba los datos se almacenan en la base datos. es decir si ejecuto la prueba 10 veces los datos se registran 10 veces y quiero evitar que eso suceda.

> como consigo que pase la prueba sin que los datos se registren permanentemente en la base de datos?

**Edicion**

Ya intente hacerlo con el trait `RefreshDatabase` y lo que pasa con RefreshDatabase, es que elimina cualquier otro dato dentro de mi base de datos, osea limpia toda la base de datos, y tampoco quiero eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

también podrías utilizar **DatabaseTransactions**, su uso sería el siguiente:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Tests\TestCase;
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
use DatabaseTransactions;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que el método `create()`, además de crear una instancia del modelo, inserta los datos a la base de datos, lo que buscas es el método [`make()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#creating-models), el cuál sólo crea modelos pero no los guarda en base datos.

```
$user = factory(User::class)->make();
```

**Edit:**

Si necesariamente tienes que insertar datos en BD. Entonces deberías usar el Trait `RefreshDatabase` de laravel, especificado [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test). El cual hace un `roll-back` a la base de datos después de cada test.

**Edit:**

Otra solución, es trabajar con `transacciones` al momento de hacer un test, Laravel provee los métodos `setUp()` y `tearDown()`, por tanto, se puede manejar así:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    DB::beginTransaction();
}

public function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

Dichos métodos deben estar dentro de tu clase test.

Comment: El caso no es tan solo ese, lo que pasa es que la ruta `api/rangos`, al cual hago la prueba es una funcion que crea un `Rango`. y tambien quiero evitar que ese se almacene. ya edite la pregunta para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: que? si sabes sabes que son las pruebas unitarias con phpUnit?, perdon pero creo que no sabes de lo que se trata el problema.

Comment: Ahora si estamos hablando del mismo tema, lo que pasa con RefreshDatabase, es que elimina cualquier otro dato dentro de mi base de datos, osea limpia toda la base de datos, es decir existen tablas en donde existen datos que si son validos y no deben de eliminarse. Pero es una buena opcion. +1